# How can I check if a number is Colorful Number?

Tags: algorithm

Colorful Number:

A number can be broken into different sub-sequence parts. Suppose, a number 3245 can be broken into parts like `3 2 4 5 32 24 45 324 245`. And this number is a colorful number, since product of every digit of a sub-sequence are different. That is, `3 2 4 5 (3*2)=6 (2*4)=8 (4*5)=20 (3*2*4)= 24 (2*4*5)= 40`

But `326` is not a colorful number as it generates `3 2 6 (3*2)=6 (2*6)=12`.

You have to write a function that tells if the given number is a colorful number or not.

Comment: Is this a project Euler problem?

Comment: Really? we have to write a function? I dont think so!

Comment: As there are finitely many colourful numbers, just look it up.

Comment: @greybeard: what if there are many of them ?

Comment: (If there are many colourful numbers, the data structure supporting look-up will be big.) (My alternative to down voting, hopefully more thought inspiring.)

Answer (score 4):

A straightforward solution is to enumerate all products and record them in a hash map.

You enumerate all products in a double loop:

- by increasing the starting index;
- then by increasing ending index, each time multiplying by the current digit.

  `3, 3.2, 3.2.4, 3.2.4.5; 2, 2.4, 2.4.5; 4, 4.5; 5`

You can verify that this generates all products. (It also generates the product of the full sequence, but this is harmless as it will not create an extra solution.)

In the worst case, i.e. the number being colorful, this will take approximately O(N²) time if you assume that hash map insertion and lookup are constant-time operations.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. But as you successfully implemented this approach, why not accept it as a solution to the original question ?

Answer (score 1):

**I already had O(n²) solution to this problem.Does anyone have better solution.**

```
package ProblemSolving;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.System;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Colorful Number:
 * A number can be broken into different sub-sequence parts.
 * Suppose, a number 3245 can be broken into parts like 3 2 4 5 32 24 45 324 245.
 * And this number is a colorful number, since product of every digit of a 
 * sub-sequence are different.
 * That is, 3 2 4 5 (3*2)=6 (2*4)=8 (4*5)=20 (3*2*4)= 24 (2*4*5)= 40
 * But 326 is not a colorful number as it generates 3 2 6 (3*2)=6 (2*6)=12.
 */
public class ColorfulNumber {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String numString = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
    int num = Integer.parseInt(numString);
    int length = numString.length();
    int[] digits = new int[length];
    int index = length - 1;
    Set<Integer> productSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

    while (num > 0) {
        digits[index] = num % 10;
        if(productSet.contains(digits[index]))
        {
            System.out.println("Not a colorful number");
            return;
        }else{
            //System.out.println("Added "+digits[index]+" at "+index);
            productSet.add(digits[index]);
        }
        num = num / 10;
        index--;
    }
    for (int x = 1; x < length; x++) {
        int product = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            product = product*digits[i];
        }

        for (int y = x; y < length; y++) {
            if(productSet.contains( product * digits[y]))
            {
                System.out.println("Not a colorful number");
                //System.out.println("Not a colorful number "+ product * digits[y]+" exists");
                return;
            }else{
                //System.out.println("Added "+ product * digits[y]);
                productSet.add( product * digits[y]);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Colorful number");
}
```

}

Comment: Note that if you limit yourself to individual digits, N cannot exceed 10, and the big O estimate becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this. If I missed out any test case please let me know.

```
public int colorful(int a) {

    String s = String.valueOf(a);

    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

    int temp = 0;

    while (temp < s.length()) {
        //If consecutive Integer is same return 0
        if (set.contains(s.charAt(temp) - '0')) return 0;
        set.add(s.charAt(temp) - '0');
        temp++;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    int n = s.length();

    int val1 = 0;
    int val2 = 0;

    while (j < n) {

        val1 = s.charAt(i) - '0';
        val2 = s.charAt(j) - '0';

        if (set.contains(val1*val2))
            return 0;

        set.add(val1 * val2);

        i++;
        j++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You are being so humble

Answer (score 1):

The following code does that you want

```
public int colorful(int A) {
    HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    while (A != 0) {
        int num = A % 10;
        numbers.add(num);
        A /= 10;
    }

    Collections.reverse(numbers);
    int n = numbers.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            int prod = 1;
            for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
                prod = prod * numbers.get(k);
            }
            if (hashSet.contains(prod))
                return 0;
            hashSet.add(prod);
        }
    }

    return 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go. :D

```
class Solution {

public int colorful(int A) {

    HashSet<Integer> map = new HashSet<>();

    char[] num = String.valueOf(A).toCharArray();

    if(num.length>10)
        return 0;

    int product[][] = new int[num.length][num.length];

    for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
        for(int j=i; j<num.length; j++){

            if(i==j){
                product[i][i] = num[i]-'0';
            }
            else product[i][j] = product[i][j-1]*(num[j]-'0');
            if(map.contains(product[i][j]))
                return 0;
            else map.add(product[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 1;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the dynamic programming solution. We start filling up the gaps till we see a product has already seen. If we don't see any product repeats till the last digit, the number is colorful.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Colorful Number: When in a given number, product of every digit of a sub-sequence are different. That number is called Colorful Number. See Example
 * Example:
 * Given Number : 3245
 * Output : Colorful
 * Number 3245 can be broken into parts like 3 2 4 5 32 24 45 324 245.
 * this number is a colorful number, since product of every digit of a sub-sequence are different.
 * That is, 3 2 4 5 (3*2)=6 (2*4)=8 (4*5)=20, (3*2*4)= 24 (2*4*5)= 40
 * Given Number : 326
 * Output : Not Colorful.
 * 326 is not a colorful number as it generates 3 2 6 (3*2)=6 (2*6)=12.
 * Resource: https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/colorful-numbers/
 */
public class ColorfulNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColorfulNumbers colorfulNumbers = new ColorfulNumbers();
        int number = 3245;
        System.out.println(colorfulNumbers.isColorful(number));
        number = 326;
        System.out.println(colorfulNumbers.isColorful(number));
    }

    /**
     * A dynamic programming solution to see if a number is colorful or not. Column 0 keeps the original digits.
     * products[i][j] means the product of the digits from index i to index j. Products[i][j] equals products[i][j-1]
     * multiply digit[j].
     *
     * @param number The input number
     * @return Whether the number is colorful or not
     */
    public boolean isColorful(int number) {
        Set<Integer> seenProducts = new HashSet<>();
        int[] digits = getDigits(number);
        int n = digits.length;
        int[][] products = new int[n][n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    int currentDigit = digits[i];
                    if (seenProducts.contains(currentDigit)) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        seenProducts.add(currentDigit);
                        products[i][j] = currentDigit;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (i < j) {
                        int previousProduct = i == j - 1 ? products[i][0] : products[i][j - 1];
                        int currentProduct = previousProduct * products[j][0];
                        if (seenProducts.contains(currentProduct)) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            seenProducts.add(currentProduct);
                            products[i][j] = currentProduct;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the digits of a number as an array.
     *
     * @param number The number
     * @return The digits of the number
     */
    private int[] getDigits(int number) {
        Stack<Integer> digitsStack = new Stack<>();
        while (number > 0) {
            int remainder = number % 10;
            digitsStack.push(remainder);
            number = number / 10;
        }
        int n = digitsStack.size();
        int[] digits = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            digits[i] = digitsStack.pop();
        }
        return digits;
    }

}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this has been posted, but it's still a recurring coding challenge, so I thought I would contribute my solution in Python.

My solution breaks up the number into a list of characters (strings of len = 1) and then uses a sliding window to get the subsequences. Once a single subsequence has been obtained, its integer product is added to a dictionary. If at anytime the dictionary already has a certain key, then return False. Otherwise, if all subseq products are unique, then return True.

```
'''
colorful uses a sliding window to get all subsequences. Then, it will check subseq. products against a dictionary to see if they've already been added. If so,
then return False. If all of the subseq products are unique, then function returns True.

The sliding window idea will add keys to the dictionary like the following.
Note: Insertion order in dictionaries is maintained in Python 3.7+
Input: 3245
1) list(check.keys()) = [3]
2) list(check.keys()) = [3, 6]
3) list(check.keys()) = [3, 6, 24]
4) list(check.keys()) = [3, 6, 24, 2]
5) list(check.keys()) = [3, 6, 24, 2, 8]
6) list(check.keys()) = [3, 6, 24, 2, 8, 40]
7) list(check.keys()) = [3, 6, 24, 2, 8, 40, 4]
8) list(check.keys()) = [3, 6, 24, 2, 8, 40, 4, 20]
9) list(check.keys()) = [3, 6, 24, 2, 8, 40, 4, 20, 5]
'''
def colorful(A):
    # break integer down into an array of numeric strings representing each digit
    # ex: an input of 3245 will create arr = ['3', '2', '4', '5']
    arr = list(str(A))
    check = {}

    # If arr is 1 unit long, then it's trivially true
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return True
    else: # case where arr is bigger than 2 units long
        win_left = 0
        win_right = 1
        while win_left <= (len(arr) - 1): # Prevents left side of window from going out of bounds
            # Making sure right side of window is only every at most 1 unit outside of arr to the right AND make sure that the window doesn't cover the whole arr
            # because, we don't want the original number itself. We just want the subsequences.
            while (win_right <= len(arr)) and (win_right - win_left < len(arr)): 
                prod = 1
                for char in arr[win_left:win_right]: # The splice here is why we are okay with the right side of window being outside of array. Splices are exclusive
                    prod *= int(char)
                if prod in check:
                    return False
                else:
                    check[prod] = 1 # add subseq prod to check dictionary and put a default value. We don't care about value.
                win_right += 1
            win_left += 1
            win_right = win_left + 1
        
        return True
```